# Bootstrap navigation sticky stays on top of page

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with Bootstrap navigation bar. I'm using sticky mode, as described in documentation:

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sticky top</a>
</nav>

<router-outlet (deactivate)="onDeactivate()"></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

When I open page, navigation bar is on top on that, as expected, but when I scroll it stays in top of page, instead top of screen (so it's not following scrollbar). Is my understanding of how it works wrong, or is it something wrong with above code. Is there a chance it's just not working because of my existing codebase (I have my page almost ready, and wanted to add this in the end).

Answer (score 0):

sticky-top simply applies a fixed position to the navbar of top:0 left:0 once you scroll down past the height of the navbar. This locks it to the top of the viewport. The underlying page will scroll as normal, but the nav will remain fixed to the top - after you scroll past it. It will not follow the scrollbar once you scroll past it.

Comment: I understand how it's working, I'm just wondering why it's not working for me. It also seems that changing to navbar-dark bg-dark has no visual effect (just font goes white, bar stays gray). Is there possibility some name clash between bootstrap and my code occurs?

Comment: "dark" is a grey. If I remember correctly is it something like #333. No, there should not be a name conflict between the two. 

Also, "sticky" uses the "sticky" CSS attribute which is not recognized by all browsers. So, it may work on one but not another. Test it in different browsers.

Firefox 58 & below, Chrome 63 & below and Safari 7 & below do not work with "sticky".

Comment: And do I properly include bootstrap to angular? I added <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"> in my index.html  head section.

Comment: I am not an Angular dev, so unfortunately I cannot help you with that part.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, I was using wrong version of Bootstrap.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Instead, I'm now using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```